# Синхронизация файлов на ftp с локальными файлами

Tags: java, синхронизация

Здравствуйте, не могу придумать алгоритм синхронизации файлов, имеется ftp(в котором время от времени обновляются файлы) и есть программа, которая при запуске должна будет сверить локальные файлы с файлами на ftp и если есть не совпадающие, то удалить не совпадающие локальные и скачать новые.

Answer (score 1):

Так а в чём проблема-то, опишите конкретнее. Сходу видится решение с двумя рекурсивными проходами:

1. обходим локальную директорию, сверяем, есть ли каждый локальный файл на FTP; если нет (был удален на FTP) или он отличается (был изменен на FTP), локальный файл удаляем;
2. обходим FTP-директорию, сверяем, существует ли каждый из файлов локально; если нет, скачиваем (отличаться файлы не могут, так как все отличающиеся мы удалили на первом шаге).

Comment: А как вы предлагаете проверять различие файлов?

Comment: @pavelip, ну, если предполагается именно описанное использование, и изначально пустая локальная директория была инциализирована файлами из FTP-директории и дальше будет обновляться по этому алгоритму, то можно просто проверять время последнего изменения файла.

Answer (score 0):

То, что вам нужно это **csync**. Вот статья на хабре по настройке кластера http://habrahabr.ru/post/120702/

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: Времени особо нет разжёвывать, в любом случае лучший вариант это rsync, но он из коробки по ftp не работает, для того и есть проверенный годами csync. :)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как на windows, но на linux есть старая, добрая команда: [rsync](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=rsync&category=1). Попробуйте её.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: rsync не работает по ftp